# how to prevent OSError: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block in a conda enironment

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I am using ubuntu `20.04` and conda `4.8.3`. I have installed a package in one of my environments using `pip` (`pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir gmsh-dev`) but when I try to import the package in a jupyter notebook, I face the following error:

```
OSError: /home/alid/miniconda3/envs/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gmsh-git-Linux64-sdk/lib/libgmsh.so: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

I have no idea what is my problem and do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in the current gmsh-dev package, use the "gmsh" python package instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed, gmsh-dev is now usable.